# meteor set environment variable permanent

Tags: meteor, environment-variables

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 lokal and running my meteorJs app on it. My MongoDB is an external DB (modulus.io).

I set my mongoDb in my console like this:

```
sudo MONGO_URL='mongodb://login@db' meteor
```

Works fine.

But everytime when I restart my lokal meteorJs App this settings seems to be resetet! So everytime when I restart my App I have to set the enviroment variable again and again ...

Is there a way to set this variable permanent in my meteorJs App so I dont have to re set it again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fast solution:

Create startup.sh and insert:

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://login@db'

meteor
```

sh startup.sh

Comment: Thanks! I will check this asap and will give a feedback!

Comment: Works perfectly! I am new to Ubuntu so this solution was new for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set environment variables that are accessed from within your app, is to put the following in your server code, i.e. for [`HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_onconnection):

```
process.env.HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT = 1
```

Doing it programmatically like this does not work for variables that need to be read during the app startup process, however - such as the MongoDB URL.